# Supervisor VS Supervisord

Tags: supervisord

I noticed that my servers have both supervisord.conf and supervisor.conf located at:
/etc/supervisord.conf
/etc/supervisor/supervisor.conf

The installed package is:
supervisor 3.2.0-2

OS version: Ubuntu 14.04/16.04

Running `lsof|grep supervisor` shows that none of the processes had neither of them open

Does anyone know the difference?
Which of the conf files is the one to take place?

Answer (score 3):

When running `supervisord` or `supervisorctl`, the program will first check the current working directory (`$CWD`, or the directory from where you invoke the command) for a `supervisord.conf` file. When absent, it will look for `/etc/supervisord.conf`. The docs will tell you more about it: http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

You also can specify the exact location of the config file by using the -c flag: `supervisord -c path/to/your/file.conf`.

So, in answer to your question: `/etc/supervisord.conf` is the one. However, if you'd like to use the other config file, you would run `supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisor.conf`.